# Detect concurrent access to a java object

Tags: java, concurrency, jsf-2

I have a question about concurrent access in java.

The project context is as follows: JSF 2.1; Richfaces 4, hibernate 3.6, spring 3.2, java 7.

I have a table that displays hundreds of thousands of folders (each folder is a java object), each table line is a dynamic link to access the consultation or modification of the object(folder).

My question is: how can I prevent more than one user from viewing or editing a folder?

In other words, how do you detect access to a folder (object java) by more than one user at the same time?

I know that with the word Synchronized on methods makes it possible to prevent concurrent access, but I want to detect concurrent access to warn the other user or the other users that the folder (object java) is already open and we have to wait for it closed.

Thank you

Comment: First, you need to put what you have tried.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you wanna do when other users are informed about which thread is currently executing inside the synchronized method? If they try to access synchronized block, they would be blocked anyway. Isn't that itself being "informed" that someone else is accessing the data?

Comment: I think I was not too clear in my explanations, imagine a web application where several managers with different profiles who access the application for consultation or modification (their profiles allow it), I simply want to display a message to warn other managers that the folder they are trying to open is busy (it is opened by a different manager) and they try later.
Access is limited to one manager at a time.
I hope I was clear this time.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any java object, how can you know that several users connected to the application are consulting or modifying it?

Comment: @ChungYang If they try to access synchronized block, they would be blocked anyway. Isn't that itself being "informed." There is no way for a thread to know that it is blocked, waiting to enter a `synchronized` statement. In fact, there is no way for the thread to do _anything at all_ until it finally is granted permission to enter. The best you could do is take a snapshot of a real-time clock immediately before and immediately after entering, and then based on the measured time difference, the thread could _guess_ whether or not it _had been_ blocked.

Comment: @ChungYang, OTOH, a thread could call `ReentrantLock.tryLock()` and do one thing if the call succeeds, or some different thing if the call fails.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization and all the other locking / blocking methods is only preventing concurrent access from within the code.

It does not prevent 2 users from editing the same "thing" at the same time. This is something you have to put into your code on your own.

There are two most common ways to achieve this:

- **Optimistic Locking**:
  You assume, that even if multiple users view the same item, there are not multiple changes at the same time. Hence, you only check during SAVING if there is a concurrent modification. To Achieve that:

  - The Object in Question needs a Timestamp, when it was last modified. (By anyone)
  - Once a user opens an item to view, you store that timestamp in the session context.
  - If the user clicks "save", you compare the session-context-timestamp with the timestamp of the actual object. If they are the same, changes can be saved. If the Object has been modified in between, you need to display an error, that it has been modified, and changes can't be saved without loading the new base-values prior.
- **Pessimistic Locking**:
  You assume, that whenever a user views an Object, that there will be a change. To Achieve that:

  - The Object in Question needs a Int-Flag, that it is currently beeing edited (By anyone - Flag = UserID)
  - Once a second user tries to load that object, you deny cause someone is editing currently.
  - Tricky part here is to clean up "locks", if the editing user just quits the page without "aborting" through application methods. To handle this, you need to define a Lock-Timestamp, define some timeout value (for example 30min) and do two more checks:

    - Editing user exceeded the timeout value upon save? he can't save anymore.
      (As an extra you can allow later saving, if the object has not been locked by someone else in between, use the lock-user-id to figure out)
    - Object is locked, but lock is older than 30 minutes? Second User can open again, claiming the lock-user-id for himself.